# Can Flex compile Flash Lite 3 and up?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, compiler-construction, flashlite

I am wondrering if Flex can compile to Flash Lite, it is from greath importance if it can, and how ( because i am not finding anywhere an option to switch or something ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash Lite 3 is still ActionScript 2, so I doubt.

I used to use [MTASC](http://www.mtasc.org/) for command line compiling for Flash Lite and going around having to use the Flash IDE.

Comment: I don't think Flex ever went anywhere near AS2 to be honest :)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that Flex 4.5 did add mobile support though, but only modern smartphones / tablets are targeted, Flash Lite is proper legacy stuff now...

Comment: Wonder if it preformance is suitable for everyday usage on such a devices :|

Comment: It's not that bad actually: http://gregsramblings.com/2011/04/26/convincing-developers-that-adobe-flex-rocks-on-android-ios-and-playbook/ – Caveat is that you have to do more ActionScript + FXG and less MXML